# How much has the power density of electrical motors and generators changed in recent decades?

Tags: motor, generator, history

I would like to know how much lighter (if at all) a matched combination of an electrical motor and generator with a given power output would be today, compared to a similarly powerful combination manufactured in the 1960s or 70s. In each case, the technological capabilities of the time should be exhausted. Money is a secondary concern.

While general trends would be the most helpful, if details are needed, they could be like this:

- Since the generator would be purpose built for just this one motor, the type and voltage of the current between the two can be chosen freely
- The rotational speed is different, maybe 40 000 RPM for the generator and 10 000 RPM for the motor
- The mechanical power from the motor should be about 15 kW
- While efficiency shouldn't be absolutely neglected, low weight is more important. I don't know what kind of efficiency I could reasonably expect.
- For the sake of simplicity, let's say no superconduction

Comment: Excellent, I look forward to your report. (I hope your spelling improves.)

Comment: I forgot that firefox doesn't spell check the heading. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: [This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032109002494#) paper gives some insight. I don't know if you can access it, as it is behind a paywall.